# Unit Testing Angular Code with a Service using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test a controller than requires me to mock a service that I'm using to get data. Currently I'm getting an error saying the function is undefined on this line:

```
dataServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('dataService', ['getFunctionStuff']);
```

According to other examples and tutorials this should be working fine.

Here's my code including the test file, the service and the controller.

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {

    dataService.getFunctionStuff($scope.foo)
      .then(function(data) {
        $scope.test = data;
      });

});
```

Service:

```
app.factory('dataService', function ($timeout, $q){

  function getFunctionStuff(formData) {
            return $http.post('../randomAPICall', formData).then(function(data) {
                return data;
            });
        };

});
```

Tests:

```
describe('Testing a controller', function() {
  var $scope, ctrl, $timeout;

  var dataServiceMock;

  beforeEach(function (){

    dataServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('dataService', ['getFunctionStuff']);

    module('myApp');

    inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q, _$timeout_) {

      $scope = $rootScope.$new();

      dataServiceMock.getFunctionStuff.and.ReturnValue($q.when('test'));

      $timeout = _$timeout_;

      ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope,
        dataService: dataServiceMock
      });
    });
  });

  it('should update test', function (){
    expect($scope.test).toEqual('test');    
  });
});
```

Here's a plunker of it: http://plnkr.co/edit/tBSl88RRhj56h3Oiny6S?p=preview

Comment: I have posted 2 ways to do the unit test. One is your way to create a spy, another is to use `$httpBackend` which is a common way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using jasmine 2.1, the API is `.and.returnValue`. And in your test spec, do `$scope.$apply()` before `then`

```
describe('Testing a controller', function () {
    var $scope, ctrl, $timeout;

    var dataServiceMock;

    beforeEach(function () {

        dataServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('dataService', ['getFunctionStuff']);

        module('myApp');

        inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $q, _$timeout_) {

            $scope = $rootScope.$new();

            dataServiceMock.getFunctionStuff.and.returnValue($q.when('test'));

            $timeout = _$timeout_;

            ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
                $scope: $scope,
                dataService: dataServiceMock
            });
        });
    });

    it('should update test', function () {
        $scope.$apply();
        expect($scope.test).toEqual('test');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why I need to use $scope.$apply()? I've tried it and its working great, I'd just like to understand.

Comment: @Blake - you need to propagate promise resolution to 'then' functions using $apply(). refer to [angular $q document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another common way to test `$http` by `$httpBackend`:

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {

    dataService.getFunctionStuff($scope.foo)
      .then(function(data) {
        $scope.test = data.data;
      });

});
```

dataService.js

```
app.factory('dataService', function($http) {

  function getFunctionStuff(formData) {
    return $http.post('../randomAPICall', formData).then(function(data) {
      return data;
    });
  }

  return {
    getFunctionStuff: getFunctionStuff
  };

});
```

specs.js

```
describe('Testing a controller', function() {
  var $scope, ctrl, $controller, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(function (){

    module('myApp');

    inject(function($injector) {

      $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
      $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
      $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

      $scope.foo = 'foo';
      $httpBackend.expectPOST('../randomAPICall', 'foo').respond(201, 'test');
      ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
    });

  });

  it('should update test', function (){
    expect($scope.test).not.toBeDefined();
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect($scope.test).toEqual('test');    
  });
});
```